Limit Per User Tokens in Drupal Simple OAuth
I'm looking for a way to limit the maximum number of tokens granted to each user in Drupal 10, similar to how we can limit the number of sessions per user using the Drupal Session Limit module. Is there a hook or a contributed module available for achieving this?
I'm exploring options to limit the maximum number of tokens granted to each user in Drupal using the Simple OAuth module. Currently, I haven't implemented any specific solution or attempted any code changes.
Could someone suggest approaches, hooks, or modules that could help achieve this? I'm looking for guidance on how to set token limits per user similar to session limits provided by other modules in Drupal.
